# I have to open modal dialog with on click function (JQUERY and Bootstrap ) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have appended the images via javascript function and JQUERY, everything is working .But now i need to add "on click" event on every image . When i click on some image there should the same photo but bigger with a modul dialog. But it does not working. I do somehting wrong somewhere . 
Tried with JQUERY "on click" function and as well with Bootstrap , but since give the appened images an ID which is taken from the array JSON object "title" property. I was not sure how to refer to it .

```
 <div id="imageContainer"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id=img01>
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

#imageContainer img {
    width: 30%;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid grey;


}

#myModal{
    display:none;
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%; /* Full width */
    height: 50%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

  /* Modal Content (image) */
  .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 200px;
  }

  /* Caption of Modal Image */
  #caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
  }


(function (){
const arrayImg = [
        {
            filename: "20140222_131314",
            title:"img1",  

        },
        {
            filename:"20140712_203709",
            title:"img2",

        },
        {
            filename:"20190318_182928",
            title:"img3"
        },
        {
            filename:"20190422_181219",
            title:"img4"
        }
    ]
    for (let i = 0 ; i< arrayImg.length ; i++) {
        const arrImg = arrayImg[i]
        const imageContainer = $("#imageContainer");
        imageContainer.append(`<img id=${arrImg.title} src=photos/${arrImg.filename}.jpg>`);
    }
   /*
   array_img.forEach()
*/

}());

let modal = $('#myModal')
let modalImg = $('#img01')

let $img = $("#imageContainer img");
$img.click(function(test){
    $('.modal').css('display',"block");
    modalImg.src = this.src


    let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() { 
        $('.modal').css('display',"none");
    }

})
///OR 
let modal = document.getElementById('myModal')
let modalImg = document.getElementById('img01')

let img = document.getElementsByTagName(" img");

img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
```

But i am not sure that `let modalImage` is refered to correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have this CSS rule:

```
#myModal{
    display:none;
}
```

also try control the modal visibility is JS with CSS clases and visibility, it's your error. **The behaviour to show and hide is automatic in bootstrap modal**, please review documentation and examples as this: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: yeah but on click i make it `display:block`

Comment: @Jefry90 I see, i did this months ago, I sorry but i think is a newbie mistake and cause problems because the bootstrap modals integrate logic to swap their visibility

Comment: I just took it  by className and not by ID , and it worked , my mistake , just in the CSS it was refered `display:none` for the class , not for the ID  :) All good. THANK YOU AGAIN .

Answer (score 0):

I made it like that and it works.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content">
</div>

let $modal = $('.modal')
let $img = $("#imageContainer img");
$img.click(function(){
    $('.modal-content').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $modal.css('display', 'block')


    let $span = $(".close");
    $span.click(function() { 
        $('.modal').css('display',"none");
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another issue similar to that and again i am stuck . 
If someone can show me my mistake , it will be great as i can NOT see it .

I have a image gallery again with every image in a separate `<div>` with same class name and i need to access the image on click and open a modal dialog with the selected image (bigger)

```
<div id="imageContainer">
 <div class="imgBox">
  <img class="jsonImage" id="image_id_001" src="Photos/_DSC0150.jpg">
  <p>Title001</p>
</div>
<div class="imgBox">
  <img class="jsonImage" id="image_id_002" src="Photos/_DSC0226.jpg">
  <p>Title002</p>
</div>
 <div class="imgBox">
  <img class="jsonImage" id="image_id_001" src="Photos/_DSC0150.jpg">
  <p>Title001</p>
</div>
<div class="imgBox">
  <img class="jsonImage" id="image_id_002" src="Photos/_DSC0226.jpg">
  <p>Title002</p>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <img id="current" class="modal-content" />
</div>
```

And part of my JS code for the modal Dialog :

```
    const modal = $('#myModal'),
    let image = $('.imgBox img')
    image.click(function() {   
        modalContent.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        modal.css('display', 'block');
        googleMap.css('display','none');

I keep getting message that `"image" is not a function'
```